# Ruby on Rails get validation error messages on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Ruby on Rails and new to this site. I am trying to get on my controller the errors from the validations I set on my model so I can change a flash message depending if this errors occurred or not.

I have this validations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :login, :password
validates_presence_of :login , :message => 'Login can't be empty'
validates_presence_of :password ,:message => 'Password can't be empty'
```

I have this  code in my controller:

```
def create
login = params[:username].downcase
password = params[:password]
tuser=User.new(login: login, password: password).save
if(tuser.errors.any?)
  flash[:title]='¡Error!'
  flash[:notice]='Please verify your data'
else
  flash[:title]='¡Success!'
  flash[:notice]='Your account was created'
end
```

And I am using this flash objects on my html to render a bootstrap modal:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;    </button>
    <h3><%= flash[:title]  %></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= flash[:notice]  %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem occurs in the controller and I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in UserController#create

undefined method `errors' for false:FalseClass
```

I want to change my flash [notice] error message to the ones thrown by the validations,
but I can't do it. I have followed some tutorials but they use the @tuser global variable on the .html file to get the validation error messages and I need to handle them on the contoller. ¿Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call save it validates and then returns `True` if the save was successful or `False` if it was not so you were setting tuser to `True` or `False` when you called save. If Save is false the errors are generated and accessible so there is no need to check for them. Try this:

```
def create
  login = params[:username].downcase
  password = params[:password]
  @tuser=User.new(login: login, password: password)
  #you could also use @tuser = User.new(params[:user]) but you will have to rename :username to :login
  if tuser.save
    flash[:title]='¡Success!'
    flash[:notice]='Your account was created'
    #redirect_to user_path(@tuser)
  else
    flash[:title]='¡Error!'
    flash[:notice]='Please verify your data'
    #render 'new'
  end
end
```

You should probably also add a redirect or render to the code as above commented out since I do not know where you are calling this from.

**Edit** 
Also adding the downcase to the model would be more inline with Rails e.g.

```
before_save {|user| user.login = login.downcase}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

Active record `save` returns either true or false, try using `create` instead, which returns object itself.

```
def create
  login = params[:username].downcase
  password = params[:password]
  tuser = User.create(login: login, password: password)
  if(tuser.errors.any?)
    flash[:title]='¡Error!'
    flash[:notice]='Please verify your data'
  else
    flash[:title]='¡Success!'
    flash[:notice]='Your account was created'
  end
end
```